Coloring a 4×4 Grid
Following up on this question:
Peter is now tasked with coloring a 4×4 grid, so that all rows, all columns and both diagonals each use all different colors. An answer to the original question uses the properties of Latin squares to show that five colors is sufficient, but unfortunately one of his markers slipped out of his pocket and down a manhole. Can he do the job with four?
I will post an answer but hide it for 48 hours. I ask experienced users to follow this pattern until the time is up, to enable beginners to try their hand.

I have added a spoiler tag to your deleted answer. It is not hidden from everyone, and the spoiler is necessary when (if) you undelete your answer.

Thanks. It is due for me to unhide/undelete when I return from work Wednesday in the USA.

This is almost a duplicate of this question about a 4x4 array of cards, and if you take the solution to that and only look at the suits you get the solution for this.

Start with the corners. All four colours must be used; place the colours arbitrarily in the corners.
(Colour-blind version on right)

 

Then choose a diagonal. For that diagonal, identify the two colours that are not used yet. Place those colours arbitrarily within the two remaining unshaded cells in the diagonal. There are two ways to do this; either way is fine. Do this for only one of the diagonals, not both.

 

Next, choose a cell that is not on a diagonal (here marked by x). It will share a row or a column with an unshaded cell on a diagonal. Note that there is only one way to shade that cell on the diagonal; here the cell on the diagonal is shown shaded incorrectly, which leaves no choices for the x cell.

 

Using the same logic, we can fill in all cells that lie on diagonals.

 

Now, there is only one way to fill in each edge-cell, because it will line up with two corners with two different colours, and two cells on diagonals, only one of which will have a different colour to the two corners.

 


Just curious. How does a colour-blind person perceive the right tables?


 Seems easy enough (or I misunderstand the rules) 
 A B C D 
 C D A B 
 D C B A 
 B A D C


You can compare with my answer when I reveal it, I won't tell now in case someone reads it.

Proof of uniqueness, up to symmetry and relabeling:

 Using similar logic to the 3×3 case, we know that the four corners are all different colors because any two lie in a line. Without loss of generality, we have
 A..B
 ....
 ....
 C..D


 The diagonal constraint means there is essentially one way to complete A (the other way is equivalent upon reflecting diagonally and interchanging B and C):
 A..B
 ...A
 .A..
 C.AD
 The rest follows.


Not starting with the corners, we can place a diagonal:
1...
.2..
..3.
...4

Which leaves 2 options

 Symmetrical
  13..
 32..
 ..3.
 ...4

 and asymmetrical

  13..
 42..
 ..3.
 ...4

The first option is quickly dismissed because

 The symmetry forces row 1 and col 1 to be the same:
  1342
 32..
 4.3.
 2..4
 Where it's impossible to place a 4 in the second column

This leaves us with

  1342
 42..
 2.3.
 3..4

Which is quickly filled without any ambiguity

  1342
 42..
 243.
 31.4
 then
  1342
 42..
 2431
 3124
 then
  1342
 4213
 2431
 3124

The only other options are by permutation of numbers or symmetry.


 yes he can:

 found by playing sudoku after filling in the first row


Both diagonals needed all different colors, sorry.

@OscarLanzi i don't know how i missed that. rotating the blue/green/green/blue middle left square by 90 degrees would solve that though.

As some other readers found during the 48 hour holding period,

 Peter can use only four colors with


 \begin{array} &\color{blue}{■}&\color{brown}{■}&\color{gold}{■}&\color{tan}{■}\\ \color{tan}{■}&\color{gold}{■}&\color{brown}{■}&\color{blue}{■}\\ \color{brown}{■}&\color{blue}{■}&\color{tan}{■}&\color{gold}{■}\\ \color{gold}{■}&\color{tan}{■}&\color{blue}{■}&\color{brown}{■} \end{array}

Hilmar was first to provide a correct answer, while matt_rule produced a detailed derivation that even includes a color-blind version. The latter appears to be different from this solution, but in fact is just a row/column transposition. Aside from this symmetry and color labellings, AxiomaticSystem proved the solution unique.
Incidentally, if we assign appropriate numerical values to the colors we can form a pandiagonal, or diabolic, magic square.
